# Node.js + jQuery Error has occurred

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jsdom

I want to retrieve a data from a database and make html file by the data.
Then to connect a database from javascript I used Node.js package "pg", and to make html file I used jQuery.

But the error "jQuery requires a window with a document" has occurred.

My source code is below

server.js

```
var pg = require('pg');
var http = require('http');
var $ = require('jquery');
var fs = require('fs');

var conString = "postgres://uname:@localhost:5432/shop";
var server = http.createServer();
server.on('request', doRequest);
server.listen(3000, 'localhost');
function doRequest(request, response) {
    var client = new pg.Client(conString);
    client.connect(function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
    }
    client.query('...', function(err, result) {
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        if(err) {
            return console.error('error running query', err);
        }
        do something;
        response.end();
        client.end();
    });
    fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err, data){
        var body = data.toString();
        console.log($(body).find('#hoge').html());
    });
});
};
```

I tried import "jsdom" like below but error "jsdom is not a function" has occurred.

server.js(fixed)

```
var pg = require('pg');
var http = require('http');
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var fs = require('fs');

var conString = "postgres://uname:@localhost:5432/shop";
var server = http.createServer();
server.on('request', doRequest);
server.listen(3000, 'localhost');
function doRequest(request, response) {
    var client = new pg.Client(conString);
    client.connect(function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
    }
    client.query('...', function(err, result) {
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        if(err) {
            return console.error('error running query', err);
        }
        do something;
        response.end();
        client.end();
    });
    fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err, data){
        var window = jsdom.jsdom(data.toString()).parentWindow;
        var $ = require('jquery')(window);
        var body = data.toString();
        console.log($(body).find('#hoge').html());
    });
});
};
```

I installed "jquery@3.2.1" and "jsdom@11.5.1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is supposed to run in a browser, not server.

Use a server side template engine, e.g. pug